# Using reinterpret_cast function cause E0109 Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type error

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I was refactoring a repository, and when I try encapsulating the code in a class:

```
class A{
    void* p = nullptr;
    void func(int value) {
        return reinterpret_cast<decltype(func)*>(p)(-1);
    }
};
```

I got this compilation error about `reinterpret_cast` :
`E0109 - Expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have (pointer-to-) function type.`
Nothing was wrong until I put the function in the class. What should I do?

Comment: Putting the function in a class will make it a method (i.e. bind it to an object by implicitly passing in the `this` pointer as the first argument), not a function. Disregarding that the code looks extremely dubious, you can't refactor it into a class.

Comment: "encapsulating the code in a class" does not just consist of "put the word `class` around it because someone said OOP is good". `class` is its own keyword and has significant behaviors that change the way your program runs and is understood. If you want to refactor a code to fit in a class, you need to think about the architecture, not just blindly add keywords to fit some arbitrary standard.

Comment: You cant cast a `void*` pointer to a pointer-to-method, because the latter does not fit inside a simple pointer to begin with.